# Как программно обновлять центр карты gMap primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Как программно обновлять центр карты `gMap` в `primefaces`?
Возможно ли это сделать изнутри бина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.xhtml:**

```
<h:form prependId="false">

    <p:commandButton value="Обновить" actionListener="#{geocodeView.updateMapCenter}" update="geoGmap" />

    <p:gmap id="geoGmap" widgetVar="geoMap" center="#{geocodeView.centerGeoMap}" zoom="2" type="ROADMAP" model="#{geocodeView.geoModel}">
    </p:gmap>

</h:form>
```

**GeocodeView.java:**

```
public class GeocodeView {

    private MapModel geoModel;
    private String centerGeoMap = "41.850033, -87.6500523";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        geoModel = new DefaultMapModel();
    }

    public void updateMapCenter(ActionEvent ae) {
        centerGeoMap = "..."; // Меняете центр карты.
    }

    ...
}
```

Более полный пример и документация доступны на [официальном сайте Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/geocode.xhtml).

Comment: спасибо. все легче, чем я думал получилось